# struggling on xpath establishment

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to establish the xpath for this page:

http://tinyurl.com/lzw44mn

Items I want to scrape are brand, model name and price respectively for all smartphones, as shown on the photo:

[image]

However I'm struggling to establish the valid main xpath. Tried to test few xpath, finishing with this one:

```
sel.xpath('//div[@style="position: relative;"]').extract()
```

but no success.

Any hints on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For brand and model name, use `class` attribute name:

```
//div[@class="m_product_title_div"]/text()
```

For the price you can check `id` attribute:

```
//div[@id="m_product_price_div"]/text()
```

Tested these xpath expressions in the chrome console (using the `$x('xpath_here')` syntax).

You probably need to make these xpath expressions relative to the block specific for the phone (`.//div[@class="m_product_title_div"]/text()`) and also [strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) the leading and trailing spaces and newlines.

---

UPD (spider that crawls brand, title and price):

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class MobiItem(Item):
    brand = Field()
    title = Field()
    price = Field()


class MobiSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "mobi"
    allowed_domains = ["mobi.ge"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://mobi.ge/?page=products&category=60"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        blocks = sel.xpath('//table[@class="m_product_previews"]/tr/td/a')
        for block in blocks:
            item = MobiItem()
            try:
                item["brand"] = block.xpath(".//div[@class='m_product_title_div']/span/text()").extract()[0].strip()
                item["title"] = block.xpath(".//div[@class='m_product_title_div']/span/following-sibling::text()").extract()[0].strip()
                item["price"] = block.xpath(".//div[@id='m_product_price_div']/text()").extract()[0].strip()
                yield item
            except:
                continue
```

crawls:

```
{'brand': u'Samsung', 'price': u'695 GEL', 'title': u'G7102 Grand dous 2'}
{'brand': u'Samsung', 'price': u'572 GEL', 'title': u'I9060 Galaxy grand...'}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

`(.//div[@class="m_product_title_div"]/text())`
returns empty strings.

Comment: @user3404005 Could you show the relevant code of your spider? So that I can debug the issue. FYI, xpaths work in the chrome console.

Comment: Haven't build the spider yet (although I have built couple of them before), because of the main xpath problem.

Comment: @user3404005 I've written the spider - check the `UPD` section.

Comment: This is a masterpiece. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Select all products using the XPath expression `//div[@class="m_product_preview_div]`. Now loop over it, and each time run those XPath queries from the context of the product fetched above:

- `./div[@class="m_product_title_div"]/span[@class="like_link"]/text()` for the vendor (given it is linked)
- `./div[@class="m_product_title_div"]/text()` for the product name
- `./div[@id="m_product_price_div"]/text()` for the price

You will very like have to trim whitespace afterwards. While this is possible using XPath and `normalize-space(...)`, I'd probably do that in Python.

Comment: Thanks. 

 `sel.xpath('//div[@class="m_product_preview_div"]').extract()` returns empty stirng when testing in terminal.